# Fotorama: captions only in fullscreen

Tags: fotorama

I would like to know if there is a possibility to show the caption only in fullscreen mode.

I need this for a custom website I an working on and the client requested that the captions only be shown in fulscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css rules

```
.fotorama .fotorama__caption {
    display: none;
}
.fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__caption {
    display: block;
}
```